# Relationship between $\mathbb{S}^{\nu}V \otimes \mathbb{S}^{\lambda}(V^{*})$ and $\mathbb{S}^{\nu / \lambda}V$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux, schur-functors

For partition $\mu$ let $\mathbb{S}^{\mu}V = V^{\otimes \mu} \cdot c_{\mu}$, where $c_{\mu}$ is the Young symmetrizer. I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{S}^{\nu / \lambda}V$ is the polynomial part of $\mathbb{S}^{\nu}V \otimes \mathbb{S}^{\lambda}(V^{*})$, that is it's isomorphic to the $\operatorname{GL}_n(V)$-submodule of $\mathbb{S}^{\nu}V \otimes \mathbb{S}^{\lambda}(V^{*})$ of all tensors on which $\operatorname{GL}_n(V)$ acts polynomially. To do so, I want to build an explicit map from $\mathbb{S}^{\nu}V \otimes \mathbb{S}^{\lambda}(V^{*})$ to $\mathbb{S}^{\nu / \lambda}V$. My idea would be something like this:
$$\mathbb{S}^{\nu}V \otimes \mathbb{S}^{\lambda}(V^{*}) \hookrightarrow \Lambda^{\nu}V \otimes \mathbb{S}^{\lambda}(V^{*}) \xrightarrow{\Delta \otimes 1} \Lambda^{\nu / \lambda}V \otimes \Lambda^{\lambda}V \otimes \mathbb{S}^{\lambda}(V^{*}) \rightarrow \Lambda^{\nu / \lambda}V \xrightarrow{\cdot a_{\nu / \lambda}} \mathbb{S}^{\nu / \lambda}V$$
$\Lambda^{\nu}V$ is $\Lambda^{\nu^{*}_1}V \otimes \Lambda^{\nu^{*}_2}V \otimes \cdots \otimes \Lambda^{\nu^{*}_s}V$, where $ \nu^{*} = (\nu^{*}_1,\nu^{*}_2,\dots,\nu^{*}_s)$ is conjugate partition, $\Lambda^{\nu / \lambda}V = \Lambda^{\nu^{*}_1-\lambda^{*}_1}V \otimes \Lambda^{\nu^{*}_2-\lambda^{*}_2}V \otimes \cdots \otimes \Lambda^{\nu^{*}_s - \lambda^{*}_s}V$; the first map is just inclusion (if you realise $\mathbb{S}^{\nu}V$ as $V^{\otimes \nu} \cdot c_{\nu}^{*}$), $\Delta$ is coproduct, the third map is the natural pairing and
$$a_{\nu / \lambda} = \sum_{\sigma \in Q_{\nu / \lambda}}\sigma$$
where $Q_{\nu / \lambda}$ is the group of row-preserving permutations.

The problem is I don't know if it's the correct map nor how to prove it is. Also, I want to avoid using LRR.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by $\Lambda^\nu V$?! This notation is highly misleading.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko, Terribly sorry. Edited the question to make it clear.